# Amicable Numbers: Runtime is to long. What could cause that? algorithm complexity?

Tags: c++, math, runtime

I've got a little runtime problem with my code. The code works fine except it takes dozens of minutes on Windows and hours on Linux to run.

```
class AmicableNumbersBeta
{
private:
    long start;
    long end;
    std::vector<long> numbers;

protected:

    long getStart() { return start;}
    long getEnd() { return end;}

    void setStart(long start) {  this->start = start;}
    void setEnd(long end) {  this->end=end;}

    long SumOfDivisors(long value)
    {
        long result = 0;
        long half_value = value / 2;

        for (long i = 1; i <= half_value; i++)
        {

           if (value % i == 0)
           {
             result += i;
           }
        }

        return result;
    }

    void AddNumber(long value)
    {
        this->numbers.push_back(value);
    }

public:

    AmicableNumbersBeta(long Start, long End) : start(Start),end(End){}


       void Calculate()
       {
       // clear old calculation, if any
       this->numbers.clear();


       for (long i = getStart(); i < getEnd(); i++)
       {

           long s1 = SumOfDivisors(i);
           long s2 = SumOfDivisors(s1);

           if (s2 == i && i < s1)
           {
            std::cout<<"-- adding ( "<<i<<" )\n";
            this->AddNumber(i);
           }
       }
    }

};
```

if i try to run this programm now and it starts to calculate Alpha til 1000000 numbers a checked it takes hours literally. *But according to my teacher it should take only a few seconds to calculate.*

```
int main() {
std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

AmicableNumbersBeta Alpha(1,1000000);
AmicableNumbersBeta Beta( 1,100000);
AmicableNumbersBeta Gamma(1,10000);
AmicableNumbersBeta Delta(1,1000);

std::cout<<"Delta\n";
Delta.Calculate();

std::cout<<"\nGamma\n";
Gamma.Calculate();

std::cout<<"\nBeta\n";
Beta.Calculate();

std::cout<<"\nAlpha\n";
Alpha.Calculate();

std::cout << "Bye, World!" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I honestly do not understand what could cause this huge "delay".

The platforms i use are Linux Debian with GCC 4.9
and Windows VS 15

I really would appreciate if someone could point out the reason for this behaviour .

Comment: You might try memoization to avoid to recompute `SumOfDivisors` for same values. Sieve can also boost the computation of divisors.

Comment: Your problem is algorithm complexity. However, you can try to parallelize your code (e.g. parallel extensions from standard library)

Comment: You need to speed up the computations of divisors - using a Sieve or similar. Recomputing SumOfDivisors for the same number is less important - half the calls of SumOfDivisors will be for 1...n and you cannot avoid them, so you memorization can roughly only cut the time in half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your code can be optimized in many ways, by using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) or [sieves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or even parallelism.

While in real applications, I may go for such optimizations, you don't need such "complex" things here - You only need a single improvement to make your code run in a few seconds instead of minutes: You need to compute divisors only up to the square root of your value. So basically:

```
long SumOfDivisors(long value)
{
    long result = 1; 

    for (long i = 2; i * i <= value; i++)
    {
       if (value % i == 0)
       {
           result += i;
           if (value / i != i) {
               result += value / i;
           }
       }
    }

    return result;
}
```

With this simple modification, you can compute Amicable numbers up to 1000000 in a few seconds.

Comment: Indeed it does work incredible fast compared to before now. But do you mind explain me why just the square root ? I do not see why...

Comment: @ExOfDe Let's say you have `A = B * C` (`B` and `C` are divisors of `A`), and let's assume that `Q` is the square root of  `A` (`Q * Q = A`). If `C >= Q`, then `B * C >= B * Q` (`B > 0`), so `A >= B * Q`, so `Q * Q >= B * Q`, so `Q >= B` (`Q > 0`) - **If `C >= Q`, then `B <= Q`**. You only need to find the "`B`", and then you can compute the `C` using `C = A / B` (`value / i` in your code).

Comment: @Holt, apologies for asking for clarifications on a 5+ year answer. But I was wondering; is the second if clause really necessary? I refactored my code into python, and removing the `if (value / i != i)` condition returned the same results. Can `value / i` even be equal to `i` if we're stopping at the sqrt of value?

Comment: @CallumMatthews This is "necessary" for perfect square, e.g., 16. For 16 you sum 1 + 2 + 4 + 8. If you remove the if then you're going to count `4` twice, which you do not want. That's basically for the last value of `i`, so this can probably be done differently to avoid checking at every iteration.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Thank you for replying. One more thing if I may; your solution is significantly more efficient than iterating until `value //2` and just summing the divisors. I still don't fully understand how. How does adding `value / i` make it quicker? Is there an algorithm I'm missing? I just want to understand it 100%. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @CallumMatthews It's simply the number of iterations. If you sum up to `value // 2`, you basically have ~value iterations, so for `value = 10e6`, you need ~10e6 iterations, if you use my code, you only need ~sqrt(10e6) = 10e3 iterations.